# where is rails installed on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I have installed rails 3.0.3 but I can not find where the source code is installed. Was it installed at  `/usr/share/rails/activerecord`? I added some debug information in (`/usr/share/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb`), but information did not print out when making a connection to a sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you run the command `gem env` it will output information about the RubyGems environment, including the path where gems are installed. The gems that comprise Rails will be in there.

Answer (score 7):

Just hit this command: `which rails` in your console!